# How to allow a user upload/edit pictures on S3 and everyone else to only read it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I am developing a mobile app and I would like for users to be able to upload pictures (then edit them if needed) for everyone else to see.

Obviously, I do not want anyone but the original uploader to be able to change their own pictures.

How can I achieve this kind of file permissions with Amazon S3? Alternatively, how can it be done with Google Cloud Storage?

I have read something about IAM and ACLs but my understanding is that IAM roles are only for users that I know in advance (e.g. my team mate). Is there a way to create an IAM account from a mobile app? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 2):

There are two general ways to do this...

**HTTP Access**

- Objects on Amazon S3 kept as **private**
- Your application always determines whether a user is permitted to read/write an object
- Your application generates [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to permit users access to private objects

This is quite a clever method because your application retains full control over who gets access to objects. When supplying a URL to access an object, the application generates a time-limited pre-signed URL that temporarily grants access. The same can be done for uploading.

**API Access**

Mobile apps can use the AWS SDK to directly call AWS services, such as uploading or downloading objects to Amazon S3.

Your server-side application can [generate temporary credentials using the AWS Secure Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) or [Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html). These credentials are passed to the mobile client, which can then make calls directly to AWS services.

This is the preferred method for mobile apps to use AWS services.

You should *not* create IAM credentials for application users — IAM credentials should only be given to your staff or your applications.

Comment: Thank you. I know there is a cost associated to Amazon Cognito (that might get quite high in my case). If I used AWS Secure Token Service to achieve what I want with my mobile app would there be a cost associated with such solution?

Comment: The [Cognito pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/) is quite low, and is free for the first 50,000 Monthly Active Users. There is no charge for IAM/STS.

Answer (score 0):

From a Google Cloud perspective, the most appropriate way to handle access to Cloud Storage buckets and the objects within them would be the use of [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists). These are a set of rules that determine what a user can do with the files stored in a bucket.

For your particular situation, you can define an ACL that allows all users to view the stored images, but only the respective owners can make changes to them. You can do this by running this command from `gcloud` with a newly created bucket:

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://[YOUR-BUCKET]
```

Once you do that, all new files uploaded to that bucket will be publicly visible, even though only the file owners can edit them.

If you already have created a storage bucket, you can also set the `public-read` ACL by running this command:

```
gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

That way, all existing files in that bucket can be viewed by any user.

There is also a way for users that access from your domain to view the stored images, which is the following:

```
gsutil acl ch -g [YOUR-DOMAIN]:R gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

You can explore additional options for setting ACLs to your Cloud Storage bucket by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists).

Comment: How does the Cloud Storage determine that the user who is trying to edit the file is the owner?

Comment: When a user uploads a file into the Cloud Storage bucket, the bucket will identify the user as the file's owner, therefore allowing them to make edits to that file and delete it if necessary. That way, you can ensure that other users can view the file, but not edit it. Check this [table](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#permissions) for further information, looking at the Default row.

Comment: You did not understand my question. Clearly, the one who created the file is owner. But how does the cloud know that the person trying to delete it is the same as the one who created it? These are REST requests, there is no state so how does Google know it's the same person?? There has to be some authentification procedure... I am asking about that.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't understand the question. Access to Cloud Storage is authenticated through [OAuth 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication). It will depend on the way access to the storage bucket, but based on your application, in this case it would take the user credentials used when signing in to confirm which user is accessing to the bucket files and act accordingly based on the user's actions.